# When create Axios instance, how to assign value from async storage in my case

Tags: react-native, axios, asyncstorage

In my react-native project, I use `async-storage` to store authorization token . I use `Axios` as HTTP client library, when I set up the header, I would like to use empty string as the value for header `Authorization` if there is no value stored in `AsyncStorage`. Otherwise use the value from the storage.

Below is the code I tried, but I get stuck on how to put the code for fetching the value from storage since it is an `await` call. I can't put it like it is now, compiler complains.  But the export Axios is an object in the file. So, any suggestions?

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import {STORAGE_KEYS} from '../constants';

// I can't put this line here
const myToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEYS.MyToken);

export default Axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://192.168.10.207:3000',
  headers: {
    Authorization: myToken ? myToken : '',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Axios Interceptors

One solution would be to use `Interceptors` :
https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import {STORAGE_KEYS} from '../constants';
import axios from 'axios;

const instance = return axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://192.168.10.207:3000' });

instance.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {

  const myToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEYS.MyToken);
  config.headers['Authorization'] = myToken ? myToken : '';
  return config;

});

export default instance;
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thank you, is it so that in the line of code when creating the `instance`, I can also declare headers with hardcoded values then using the interceptor to add new headers?

Comment: Yes you can ! As far as I understand you can completely change the whole request using interceptors ! Let me know if you have troubles with this ...